# Controller ValidateRequests laravel

Tags: php, laravel

When trying to confirm by email I get this output:

> PHP Fatal error: Trait "App\Http\Controllers\ValidateRequests" not
> found in app/Http/Controllers/CiudadanoController.php on line 16.

The line 16 is on:

```
class CiudadanoController extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
```

this is the controller code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Ciudadano;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class CiudadanoController extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable;
    use ValidateRequests;


    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $validated = $this->validate($request, [
            'cuil' => 'required',
            'nombre' => 'required',
            'apellido' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);
    
        $ciudadano = Ciudadano::create($validated);

        
        $ciudadano->save();
        event(new Registered($ciudadano));

        return("nice");

 }
```

Comment: The ```use``` declarations should be placed above the class.

Comment: It should be `ValidatesRequests`, note the `s` in the middle

Comment: @Innovin It's a trait, so the use statement is in the right place

Comment: Yeah, for traits in Laravel, it is very common to see `use Path\To\MyTrait;` before the `class ...` definition, then `use MyTrait` within the class. Since Laravel heavily uses namespaces, if you try to call `use MyTrait`, and it has a different namespace, it will fail with the message in the question. If they share the same namespace, then you don't have to; `use MyTrait;` within the class is all that's required. Spelling the trait correctly is another, separate issue though 

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the trait name without a namespace prefix if they are not imported and not in the same namespace. You should import the trait of `Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests` or add a namespace prefix.

Alternative 1:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Ciudadano;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

############
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
############

class CiudadanoController extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    ###
    use ValidatesRequests;
    ###

    // ...
}
```

Alternative 2:

```php
// ...

class CiudadanoController extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable;

    ####
    use \Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
    ####


    // ...
}
```